# How to convert 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, text, type-conversion, controls

As I read the base class of `TextBlock` is `Control` ([as said here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls?view=net-5.0)). I'm trying to convert a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` instance to `System.Windows.Controls.Control` as following:

```
Control c1 = TbPosDir;
```

where `TbPosDir` is a `TextBlock` but I get following error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to
> 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' ...

How can I do aforementioned conversion?

Note that I can convert other `Control` instances  such as `TextBox` to a `Control` without any problem:

```
var txt = new TextBox();
Control c2 = txt;
```

Comment: You must have misunderstood that page. "*Provides a lightweight control for displaying small amounts of flow content*" does not mean it is derived from Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right - `TextBlock` does not have `Control` anywhere in its inheritance hierarchy, which is:

- `Object`

  - `DispatcherObject`

    - `DependencyObject`

      - `Visual`

        - `UIElement`

          - `FrameworkElement`

            - `TextBlock`

`Control` is another class directly derived from `FrameworkElement`. Presumably `TextBlock` doesn't derive from `Control` because it doesn't have a `ControlTemplate`.

So no, you can't use a `TextBlock` as a `Control`... but you *probably* don't need to. You haven't shown what you're trying to do with the control, but in *most* cases I suspect you'll be fine with `FrameworkElement` or even one of the base classes such as `Visual`.

Answer (score 0):

TextBlock derives from FrameworkElement, not from Control

```
public class TextBlock : FrameworkElement, IServiceProvider, IContentHost, IAddChild, IAddChildInternal
```